# Use default gateway as ntp server

Tags: linux, debian, ntp

I have a lot of servers running debian and they all must synchronize clock to NTP server running on their respective default gateway. Since there is many servers on many different network segments, I had to find out what the gateway IP address is and manually change `/etc/ntp.conf` for each server.

Since this took some time and I know the network structure changes from time to time, I'm wondering if there is some *easy way* (easier than manually changing ip addresses every year or so) of setting ntp client to "automatically synchronize to default gateway" mode. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Use broadcasting server?

Comment: @yaegashi I'm not sure I understand (I'm not admin - I'm just a programmer who has to do some administration because nobody else can) - but if I do understand, you suggest that NTP servers (the gateways) should broadcast ? If that is so, I can't do that, because I do not have access to gateways.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but would `broadcastclient` be a useful configuration option for you?

Comment: @JeffSchaller wouldn't that require also setting servers to broadcast (and I have no control over NTP servers on gateways) ?

Comment: Not sure, Jan. To yaegashi's question, on one of your (working) debian servers, if you run `ntpq -c peers`, what is the value of the "t" (type of peer) field? Another off-the-wall option would be to configure all of your servers with every known NTP server and allow each server (NTP client) to sort out the best for itself. (May run into extra firewall traffic, if those are around).

Comment: @JeffSchaller there is "u" under "t". As for all known NTP servers - the network admin decided that all gateways will act as NTP servers and the actual NTP server (or servers, I don't know how many there are) to which the gateways synchronize are unknown to me. Also the gateways are on different network segments and usually I can't connect to other gateways from "my" servers.

Comment: I've created a chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/27462/use-default-gateway-as-ntp-server?tab=general to continue the discussion...

Answer (score 3):

After a discussion with Jeff Schaller, I just added a simple `init.d` script called `set-gateway-as-ntp` which runs before ntp and adds the gateway address to `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          setgatewayasntp
# Required-Start:    $network
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Start-Before:    $ntp
# Short-Description: Set gateway as NTP server
# Description:       Set gateway address to /etc/ntp.conf
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Set Gateway as NTP"

. /lib/init/vars.sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
    gateway_ip=`ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $3}'`
    sed -i /etc/ntp.conf -e "s/^server .*/server $gateway_ip/"
    ;;
  stop)
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

I'm not very proud of this solution, but it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to provide a ntp-servers optino in your dhcp leases:

```
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 192.168.10.1;
    option ntp-servers 192.168.10.1, 192.168.10.50;
    BLAH BLAH
 }
```

By default debian's ntp package comes with a dhcp-exit hook that adds ntpservers listed in the dhcp lease to the ntp.conf.

Comment: Unfortunately, DHCP is not used there